# Lebesgue integrals vs. Multiple improper Riemann integrals

Tags: real-analysis

I know that  *On a non-compact interval on $\mathbb{R}$, a function is Lebesgue integrable if and only if its improper Riemman integral is absolutely convergent. In this case, both of the integrals are coincide*. In terms of multiple improper Riemann integrals in $\mathbb{R^n}$,it embraces both the case of the unbounded domain of integration and the case of the unbounded funcation.Whether we have some similar conclusions?
e.g.Let $D$ be an open unbounded set of  $\mathbb{R^n}$,whether we have that the multiple improper Riemann integral of $|f(\mathbb{x})|$ in $D$ is convergent iff $f(\mathbb{x})$ is Lebesgue integrable on $D$.In this case,two integrals are the same? I am sorry to say that I have little knowledge about Lebesgue integrals. Maybe it's a simply fundamental question.

---

**Def**.Let $D$ be a set in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$(possibly unbounded).An *exhaustion* of $D$ is a sequence of *Jordan-measurable* sets $D_{k}$ such that $D_{1}\subset D_{2}\subset D_{3}\subset \cdots\subset D$ with $D=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} D_{k}$

**Multiple improper Riemann integrals**.Let ${D_{k}}$ be an exhaustion of the set $D\subseteq \mathbb{R^{n}}$ and suppose $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable over each $D_{k}.$If the limit $$\int_{D}f=\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{D_{k}}f $$ exists and has a value independent of the choice of the sets in the exhaustion of $D$,this limit is called the *Multiple improper Riemann integrals of $f$ over $D$*.When this limit is *finite*,we say that the integral *converges* and $f$ is integrable over $D$.If there is no common limit for all exhaustions of $D$ or its value is $\pm\infty,$we say the integral *diverges* and $f$ is not integrable.

Comment: it's not clear what your question is. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Everything follows from the following fact: if $A\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ is a closed rectangle and $f:A\to\Bbb{R}$ is a (properly) Riemann-integrable function, then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable over $A$ and the two integrals coincide. To address the question of possibly unbounded open sets $D$, can you write out the precise definition of the improper Riemann integral over $D$?

Comment: it is only a one way implication, but yes, if $f$ is measurable and $|f|$ is improper Riemann integrable then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and the integrals coincide. See Dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: The name is Riemann, not Riemman.

Comment: and now how is the integral over a Jordan-measurable subset defined? Do you see how this all links back together to my previous comment? (of course at some point you'll have to use Lebesgue's DCT as well)

Comment: @peek-a-boo The subset $D\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is Jordan-measurable subset means $D$ is bounded subset in $ \mathbb{R^n}$ and the boundary of $D$,$\partial D$, has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: ok, that's the definition of Jordan-measurable. How is the integral over Jordan-measurable sets defined? I'm only getting you to write out all these definitions because at the end of the day, your question boils down to understanding these definitions, the remark I made above regarding the connection between proper Riemann-integrability, and finally dominated/monotone convergence.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for your hints. Let me back to defintions to understand its connection.